# I don't know why UnboundLocalError is occured

Tags: python

```
count = 0

def test():
    number = 3
    while count < 6:
        count = number + 3

test()
```

The above code generates the following error.

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

```
count = 0

def test():
    number = 3
    while count < 6:
        print(count)
        break

test()
```

But the code above runs well.

What is the difference between the two codes?

Comment: The difference is that the first one assigns the variable in the function, which makes it a local variable. The second one only reads the variable, so it uses the global variable.

Comment: you need ```def test(count)``` and you need then to ```test(count)```

Comment: Or if you intend to modify the global variable (which is not good style - you should generally avoid globals for all osrts of reasons), add `global count` in the function.